# Finding pressure using Bernoulli's Theorem

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

The inviscid irrotational ﬂow around a circular cylinder of radius $a$ is described by the complex potential $$w =Uz+ \frac{Ua^2}{z}$$  where $U$ is a positive constant.

I found $\psi=U \cos \theta (r+a^2/r)$ and $\phi= U\sin \theta (r-a^2/r)$

And $u_r=U\cos \theta (a^2/r^2 +1)$ and $u_{\theta}=U\sin \theta (a^2/r^2 -1)$

Use Bernoulli’s theorem to determine the pressure on $r =a$. Explain why this result in unphysical.

---

Is this what we are supposed to do: By Bernoulli theorem, we have $$\frac p{\rho} +\textbf u ^2/2= \text{constant}$$ Are we then meant to sub $\textbf u $ as $u_{r}$ for some reason to get: $$p=\frac{\rho}2 u_r +C$$ $$p(r=a, \theta)=2U^2 \rho \cos^2 \theta+C$$ Is that what we are meant to do to find the pressure on $a$?

I am unsure about the second part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the potential and stream function switched.  The correct velocity components are

$$u_r = U \cos \theta(1 - a^2/r^2), \\ u_\theta = -U \sin \theta(1 +a^2/r^2).$$

At the surface of the cylinder $r = a$ we have $u_r|_{r=a} = 0$ and $u_\theta|_{r=a} = -2U \sin \theta$.

Using Bernoulli's equation the pressure on the surface is

$$p =  C + \frac{\rho}{2}|\mathbb{u}|^2|_{r=a} = C + \frac{\rho}{2}(u_r^2|_{r=a} +u_\theta^2|_{r = a}) = C- 2 \rho U^2 \sin^2 \theta.$$

The result is unphysical because the pressure distribution is symmetrical. The values of pressure at the front ($\theta = 0$) and rear ($\theta = \pi$) stagnation points are equal.  In reality for viscous flow, the pressure is lower in the wake behind the cylinder resulting in a net resultant force (form drag).

Comment: What does it exactly mean by "unphysical" though? Like if it was, what would the situation be? Also, the sketch of the streamlines would be very similar to the other sketch I did in my other question right??

Comment: Yes, the streamlines are very similar.  Unphysical means not providing a realistic model for actual behavior observed in the real world.  Clearly bodies with fluid streaming past experience a drag force.  Surely you have experienced what it feels like walking against a strong wind. Some of the drag comes from shear stress at the surface due to viscosity.  This is neglected in inviscid flow.  But there should still be a net force due to pressure (called form drag).  The inviscid solution here produces no drag force since the pressure profile is the same on the upstream and downstream sides.